# array list error in dijkstra algoritim java

Tags: java, arraylist, dijkstra

I want to use dijkstra algorithm with data which I get from database
here is my past of code:

```
 List ed = new ArrayList();
    while(rscost.next())
                    {

                        int cost = Integer.parseInt(rscost.getString(3));
                        Vertex v2=  hst.get(rscost.getString(1));// get Vertex from hastable
                    ed.add(new Edge(v2,cost));                  
                    }
v1.adjacencies= new Edge[]{ed};
```

v1 is another vertex and my main object is creating object:

```
v1.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v0, 5),
                                 new Edge(v2, 3),
                                 new Edge(v4, 7) };
```

like in the examples.

It throws `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List to Edge.`.

If I cast ed to edge it throws `null` value.

What should I do add this elements?

Answer (score 0):

Given that `adjacencies` is an array of Edges, then you can only populate `adjacencies` with objects of type `Edge`.

```
v1.adjacencies= new Edge[]{ed};
```

This line is trying to populate `adjacencies` with a List object, not an Edge object. Since the variable `ed` cannot be cast from a List to an Edge, you are getting a Type Mismatch error.

Instead, you will need to take your List and convert it into an array of Edges. Or you can make adjacencies a List object instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

The way you convert from list to array is wrong. First of you should use generics, i.e.

```
List<Edge> ed = new ArrayList<Edge>();
```

secondly you need to convert the array differently:

```
v1.adjacencies = ed.toArray(new Edge[ed.size()])
```

If you are using an older version of Java, you could iterate over the List and copy it into an array.